# Operator precedence in regular expressions

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle11g, operator-precedence

What is the default operator precedence in Oracle's regular expressions when they don't contain parentheses?

For example, given

```
 H|ha+
```

would it be evaluated as `H|h` and then concatenated to `a` as in `((H|h)a)`, or would the `H` be alternated with `ha` as in `(H|(ha))`?

Also, when does the `+` kick in, etc.?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Given the [Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm#CHDIDJJC):

> Table 4-2 lists the list of metacharacters supported for use in regular expressions passed to SQL regular expression functions and conditions. These metacharacters conform to the POSIX standard; any differences in behavior from the standard are noted in the "Description" column.

And taking a look at the `|` value in that table:

> The expression a|b matches character a or character b.

Plus taking a look at the [POSIX doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/basic_extended.html#boost_regex.syntax.basic_extended.operator_precedence):

> Operator precedence
>   The order of precedence for of operators is as follows:
>
> 1. Collation-related bracket symbols [==] [::] [..]
> 2. Escaped characters \
> 3. Character set (bracket expression) []
> 4. Grouping ()
> 5. Single-character-ERE duplication * + ? {m,n}
> 6. Concatenation
> 7. Anchoring ^$
> 8. Alternation |

I would say that `H|ha+` would be the same as `(?:H|ha+)`.

Comment: ?: in (?: ...) is not Oracle syntax.

Comment: @mathguy I agree but I wanted to show that it's not the same than `(H|ha+)` because there were no capturing group

Comment: As Thomas has shown, alternation (the | operator) has the lowest precedence. A regexp search with H|ha+ will try with H first, and only if it can't find a match (after trying all the combinations indicated by other operators), as a last resort, it will try again with ha+ instead of H. The + is a unary operator, it attaches to a only and greediness applies.

Comment: Interesting question regarding precedence: if you have two "alternation" groups, in which order are they evaluated? Answer - the first choice in the first alternation is tried with all the choices in the second alternation, and if that doesn't find any match, then the second choice in the first alternation is tried. `select regexp_substr('adibcd', '(a|b)(c|d)') from dual;` returns 'ad' (the other choice would have been 'bc', but after checking for ac, the regexp checks for ad before trying bc).

Comment: @ThomasAyoub What would be the precedence of the dot operator (".")? Same as the other wildcard operators? I can't seem to find the answer to that anywhere.

Comment: @Venom `.` is not a operator, it's a kind of character class, like `\d` or `\w` can be

Comment: @ThomasAyoub That would mean that it has no precedence defined as such, not being an actual operator?

Comment: @Venom it, indeed, not being an actual operator, it represent one of *every character that is not a new line*. Am I being clear or do you want to start a chat?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub No need, everything is much clearer now. Thank you.

Comment: so, H|ha+ is the same evaluation as as (H|ha+) and (?:H|ha+).  Yes, re and (re) and (?:re) all match the same thing.  Necessarily.
That is literally a useless answer and does answer the original question.

Comment: The first two quotations are not relevant to the answer. In general, I think it's okay to introduce some more original context; however, the `Plus` before the last quotation makes it appear as if all quotations are needed for the answer.

Answer (score 22):

Using capturing groups to demonstrate the order of evaluation, the regex `H|ha+` is equivalent to the following:

```
(H|(h(a+)))
```

This is because the precedence rules (as seen below) are applied in order from the highest precedence (the lowest numbered) one to the lowest precedence (the highest numbered) one:

- Rule 5 → `(a+)` The `+` is grouped with the `a` because this operator works on the preceding single character, back-reference, group (a "marked sub-expression" in Oracle parlance), or bracket expression (character class).
- Rule 6 → `(h(a+))` The `h` is then concatenated with the group in the preceding step.
- Rule 8 → `(H|(h(a+)))` The `H` is then alternated with the group in the preceding step.

---

Precedence table from section [9.4.8 of the POSIX docs for regular expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04_08) (there doesn't seem to be an official Oracle table):

```
+---+----------------------------------------------------------+
|   |             ERE Precedence (from high to low)            |
+---+----------------------------------------------------------+
| 1 | Collation-related bracket symbols | [==] [::] [..]       |
| 2 | Escaped characters                | \<special character> |
| 3 | Bracket expression                | []                   |
| 4 | Grouping                          | ()                   |
| 5 | Single-character-ERE duplication  | * + ? {m,n}          |
| 6 | Concatenation                     |                      |
| 7 | Anchoring                         | ^ $                  |
| 8 | Alternation                       | |                    |
+---+-----------------------------------+----------------------+
```

The table above is for Extended Regular Expressions. For Basic Regular Expressions see [9.3.7](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_07).

Comment: Does Java regex support collation symbols?

Comment: @VictorGrazi Collation symbols are defined in the POSIX standard, but unfortunately they are not widely supported. The Java `regex` package implements a "Perl-like" regex engine, missing a few features (e.g. conditional expressions and comments), but including some extra ones (e.g. possessive quantifiers and variable-length, but finite, look-behind assertions). Neither Perl nor Java supports collating sequences or character equivalences. However,Perl *does* support "proper" POSIX  character classes, although Java only supports them using the \p operator (with a few caveats).

Comment: Where is the place for back referencing if we include it in the ERE precedence table?