# How to combine multiple regex into single one in python?

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I'm learning about regular expression. I don't know how to combine different regular expression to make a single generic regular expression.

I want to write a single regular expression which works for multiple cases. I know this is can be done with naive approach by using *or* *" | "* operator.

I don't like this approach. Can anybody tell me better approach?

Answer (score 41):

You need to compile all your regex functions. Check this example:

```
import re
re1 = r'\d+\.\d*[L][-]\d*\s[A-Z]*[/]\d*'
re2 = '\d*[/]\d*[A-Z]*\d*\s[A-Z]*\d*[A-Z]*'
re3 = '[A-Z]*\d+[/]\d+[A-Z]\d+'
re4 = '\d+[/]\d+[A-Z]*\d+\s\d+[A-Z]\s[A-Z]*'

sentences = [string1, string2, string3, string4]
for sentence in sentences:
    generic_re = re.compile("(%s|%s|%s|%s)" % (re1, re2, re3, re4)).findall(sentence)
```

Comment: @Amit Iv'e fixed it. I used the variable name that you wrote "generic-re" and it cause the error.

Comment: Character class with only one element is a nonsens and make regex harder to read.

Comment: Thanks working!! I got the answer for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53947401/how-to-check-with-more-regex-for-one-address-in-python-using-re-findall/53954202#53954202

Comment: variable `sentence` is not defined + `findall` takes a string not a list. maybe you meant to do `for sentence in sentences`?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/36870447/288875 to confirm that the `|` operator in fact has the lowest precedence (i.e. it has a 'weaker binding force' than any other operator which may be used in any of `re1`...`re4`).

Answer (score 15):

To  `findall` with an arbitrary series of REs all you have to do is concatenate the list of matches which each returns:

```
re_list = [
    '\d+\.\d*[L][-]\d*\s[A-Z]*[/]\d*', # re1 in question,
    ...
    '\d+[/]\d+[A-Z]*\d+\s\d+[A-z]\s[A-Z]*', # re4 in question
]

matches = []
for r in re_list:
   matches += re.findall( r, string)
```

For efficiency it would be better to use a list of compiled REs.

Alternatively you could join the element RE strings using

```
generic_re = re.compile( '|'.join( re_list) )
```

Comment: Are you sure the above works? I get `'str' object has no attribute 'findall'` just by copying and pasting.

Comment: @gented Silly error on my part, Any variable name except re, which is what you imported! I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I see lots of people are using pipes, but that seems to only match the first instance. If you want to match all, then try using lookaheads.

Example:

```
>>> fruit_string = "10a11p" 
>>> fruit_regex = r'(?=.*?(?P<pears>\d+)p)(?=.*?(?P<apples>\d+)a)'
>>> re.match(fruit_regex, fruit_string).groupdict()
{'apples': '10', 'pears': '11'}
>>> re.match(fruit_regex, fruit_string).group(0)
'10a,11p'
>>> re.match(fruit_regex, fruit_string).group(1)
'11'
```

`(?= ...)` is a look ahead:

> Matches if ... matches next, but doesn’t consume any of the string. This is called a lookahead assertion. For example, Isaac (?=Asimov) will match 'Isaac ' only if it’s followed by 'Asimov'.

`.*?(?P<pears>\d+)p` 
find a number followed a p anywhere in the string and name the number "pears"

Comment: at first i didn't understand what you meant by 'that only seems to match the first instance' but then i realized you were looking to find the _first_ match of multiple regexes in one pass, instead of _every_ match of multiple regexes (which the other answers have shown can be done with something like `find_all`). that's an interesting problem to solve. neat solution. though i'm not sure how you got `'10a,11p'` from `group(0)`. when i ran it it just gave me `''`. did you mean `groups()`?

Answer (score 0):

You might not need to compile both regex patterns. Here is a way, let's see if it works for you.

```
>>> import re
>>> text = 'aaabaaaabbb'
>>> A = 'aaa'
>>> B = 'bbb'
>>> re.findall(A+B, text)
['aaabbb']
>>>
```

further read [read_doc](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#Module-Level-Functions)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to squash multiple regex patterns together the result can be annoying to parse--unless you use `P<?>` and `.groupdict()` but doing that can be pretty verbose and hacky. If you only need a couple matches then doing something like the following could be mostly safe:

```py
bucket_name, blob_path = tuple(item for item in matches.groups() if item is not None)
```