# How to check with more RegEx for one address in python using re.findall()

Tags: python, regex

How to check with more RegEx for one address in python using re.findall()

Ex: I want to apply the below regex rules

```
 # need to get address
    txt = "hello user 44 West 22nd Street, New York, NY 12345 from"    
    regexp = "[0-9]{1,3} .+, .+, [0-9]{5}"
    regexp1 = "[0-9]{1,3} .+, .+, [A-Z]{2} [0-9]{5}"
    regexp2 = "[0-9]{1,3} .+, .+, [A-Z]{2} [0-9]{9}"    
    re.findall(regexp, regexp1, regexp2, txt)
```

is this correct? I am getting error of this code

Comment: Are you sure that regular expressions are the appropriate tool for this job?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Perhaps more important, do any of those regex patterns even work on this input address string?

Comment: Did you take a look at manual?

Comment: If you are getting error, then that's probably not correct. What is the error message? What do you expect?

Comment: findall doesn't take multiple patterns. `re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)`

Comment: `re.findall` only takes one regex pattern... however, it does look like you can make a single pattern there and use `re.search` with match groups - `re.findall` doesn't look like what you want here...

Comment: BTW you can use one regex `[0-9]{1,3} .+, .+,(?: [A-Z]{2})? [0-9]{5,9}`

Comment: Guys Thanks for you replay.. Just i want to check more regex (more then 20 diff types for the raw data) in this single line re.findall() how can i check? its possible?

Comment: first this correct syntax  "re.findall(regexp, regexp1, regexp2, txt)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got answer from here

[How to combine multiple regex into single one in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42136040/how-to-combine-multiple-regex-into-single-one-in-python)

Working fine this

```
import re
re1 = r'\d+\.\d*[L][-]\d*\s[A-Z]*[/]\d*'
re2 = '\d*[/]\d*[A-Z]*\d*\s[A-Z]*\d*[A-Z]*'
re3 = '[A-Z]*\d+[/]\d+[A-Z]\d+'
re4 = '\d+[/]\d+[A-Z]*\d+\s\d+[A-z]\s[A-Z]*'

sentences = [string1, string2, string3, string4]
generic_re = re.compile("(%s|%s|%s|%s)" % (re1, re2, re3, re4)).findall(sentence)
```