# Combine multiple regex expressions in Python

Tags: python, regex

For clarity, i was looking for a way to compile multiple regex at once.
For simplicity, let's say that every expression should be in the format `(.*) something (.*)`.
There will be no more than 60 expressions to be tested.

As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42136040/how-to-combine-multiple-regex-into-single-one-in-python), i finally wrote the following.

```py
import re
re1 = r'(.*) is not (.*)'
re2 = r'(.*) is the same size as (.*)'
re3 = r'(.*) is a word, not (.*)'
re4 = r'(.*) is world know, not (.*)'

sentences = ["foo2 is a word, not bar2"]

for sentence in sentences:
    match = re.compile("(%s|%s|%s|%s)" % (re1, re2, re3, re4)).search(sentence)
    if match is not None:
        print(match.group(1))
        print(match.group(2))
        print(match.group(3))
```

As regex are separated by a pipe, i thought that it will be automatically exited once a rule has been matched.

Executing the code, i have

```
foo2 is a word, not bar2
None
None
```

But by inverting re3 and re1 in re.compile `match = re.compile("(%s|%s|%s|%s)" % (re3, re2, re1, re4)).search(sentence)`, i have

```
foo2 is a word, not bar2
foo2
bar2
```

As far as i can understand, first rule is executed but not the others. 
Can someone please point me on the right direction on this case ?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 2):

There are various issues with your example:

1. You are using a *capturing* group, so it gets the index `1` that you'd expect to reference the first group of the inner regexes. Use a non-capturing group `(?:%s|%s|%s|%s)` instead.
2. Group indexes increase even inside `|`. So`(?:(a)|(b)|(c))` you'd get:

   ```
   >>> re.match(r'(?:(a)|(b)|(c))', 'a').groups()
   ('a', None, None)
   >>> re.match(r'(?:(a)|(b)|(c))', 'b').groups()
   (None, 'b', None)
   >>> re.match(r'(?:(a)|(b)|(c))', 'c').groups()
   (None, None, 'c')
   ```

   It seems like you'd expect to only have one group 1 that returns either `a`, `b` or `c` depending on the branch... no, indexes are assigned in order from left to right without taking account the grammar of the regex.

The [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module does what you want with numbering the groups. If you want to use the built-in module you'll have to live with the fact that numbering is not the same between different branches of the regex *if* you use named groups:

```
>>> import regex
>>> regex.match(r'(?:(?P<x>a)|(?P<x>b)|(?P<x>c))', 'a').groups()
('a',)
>>> regex.match(r'(?:(?P<x>a)|(?P<x>b)|(?P<x>c))', 'b').groups()
('b',)
>>> regex.match(r'(?:(?P<x>a)|(?P<x>b)|(?P<x>c))', 'c').groups()
('c',)
```

(Trying to use that regex with `re` will give an error for duplicated groups).

Answer (score 1):

Giacomo answered the question.
However, I also suggest: 1) put the "compile" before the loop, 2) gather non empty groups in a list, 3) think about using (.+) instead of (.*) in re1,re2,etc.

```
    rex= re.compile("%s|%s|%s|%s" % (re1, re2, re3, re4))
    for sentence in sentences:
        match = rex.search(sentence)
        if match:
            l=[ g for g in match.groups() if g!=None ]
            print(l[0],l[1])
```