# Script to find a series of words on a webpage and output if found

Tags: python

The code is working if it's just one word. However, I want to find a series of words. If any of those words (ex. ["Mobile", "standalone", "desktop"]) pops up, it should output that found word. Any ideas?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
browser.get('https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/home?authuser=0')




while True:
   
    browser.refresh()
    sourcetext=browser.page_source
    searchword= ["Mobile", "standalone", "desktop"]
  
    if (searchword in sourcetext):
    
        print("FOUND!" + searchword)
        now = datetime.now()
        current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        print("Current Time =", current_time)

    else:

        print("not found")

    
    sleep(5)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to combine multiple regex into single one in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42136040/how-to-combine-multiple-regex-into-single-one-in-python)

Comment: @AlexReynolds thanks, but this is not what i'm looking for. I'm looking for a simple solution with array of strings or so.

Comment: You need to iterate over *searchword* checking for the existence of every word in the list. However, even when you do that, you could get ambiguous results

Comment: @JCaesar so, maybe do it with bunch of nested IF Else Else would solve this, I guess. But that would not be a pretty solution. What if the array consists of 10 words, the nested if would be a disaster to look at.

Comment: Hint: *for word in searchword; if word in sourcetext*

Comment: @JCaesar thank you! It worked, but I have no idea why. What is this "word" thingy? Some sort of predefined function/variable that does magic?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here:

```
 if (searchword in sourcetext):
```

'searchword' is not a single word but is a collection. when you try to use it like that (acting like it's a single word) only the first word will be searched.

So the solution here is to iterate over the 'searchword' and then search for the words inside it on the sourcetext.

Here's the last part of your code:

```
while True:
   
    browser.refresh()
    sourcetext=browser.page_source
    searchword= ["Mobile", "standalone", "desktop"]
    
    for word in searchword:
        if word in sourcetext:
    
            print("FOUND!" + word)
            now = datetime.now()
            current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
            print("Current Time =", current_time)

        else:
            print("not found")
    sleep(5)
```

Comment: Thank you! I figured that too. I just need a for loop to iterate through the entire list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use intersection function by converting string to array.

This code print intersect words between searchword and sourcetext.

```
print( set(sourcetext.split()).intersection(searchword) )
```

Comment: This is advanced. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @JCaesar, it worked. But I have no idea of why it worked.

```
while True:
       
        browser.refresh()
        sourcetext=browser.page_source
        searchword= ["Starwars", "Citizen"]
    
        for word in searchword:
      
            if word in sourcetext:
        
                print("FOUND!" + word)
                now = datetime.now()
                current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
                print("Current Time =", current_time)
    
            else:
    
                print("not found")
    
        
        sleep(5)
```

Comment: *word* is just a variable name. There's no 'magic' here. Also, you don't need the parentheses - i.e., *if word in sourcetext:* will suffice

Comment: @JCaesar ah, gotcha, I'm still in C++ world. Python syntax is getting some used to. Thanks!